# Boost TCP server not able to receive string messages with \0 in the end

Tags: boost, boost-asio

The server works fine and receives all the messages when there are not prepended with \0.

Suppose if i send a message like
"Message" , and send it 100 times to the server all the messages are received by the server but if i add \0 in the end like "Message\0"  , than the server only receives couple messages.

This is the code for the TCP server.

```
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/write.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <global.h>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>


using boost::asio::ip::tcp;



class session
    : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
    session(tcp::socket socket)
        : socket_(std::move(socket))
    {
        
    }

    void start()
    {
        
        do_read();
    }

private:
    void do_read()
    {
    
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
            [this, self  ](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
                if (length > 0) {
                
                    std::string strData(data_, length);
                    std::cout << strData;
                    
        
                    if (strData.find_first_not_of(' ') != std::string::npos)
                    {
                        // There's a non-space.
                        commandsQueue.push(strData);
                    }
                    
                }
                
                    do_write(length);
                
            }
        });
        
    }

    void do_write(std::size_t length)
    {
        
        if (stdqueAnswers.size() > 0) {
            auto self(shared_from_this());
            std::string stdstrAnswer = stdqueAnswers.front();
            boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(stdstrAnswer.c_str(), stdstrAnswer.length() ),
                [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
            {
                if (!ec)
                {
                    do_read();
                }
            });

            stdqueAnswers.pop();
        }
        else {

            auto self(shared_from_this());
        
            

             do_read();
        }
    }

    tcp::socket socket_;
    enum { max_length = 8096 };
    char data_[max_length];
};

class server {
public:
    server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, short port)
        : acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
    {
        acceptor_.listen();
        do_accept();
    }

private:
    void do_accept()
    {
        acceptor_.async_accept(
            make_strand(acceptor_.get_executor()),
            [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
            
                if (!ec) {
                    std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
                    do_accept();
                }
            });
    }

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought what's likely happening is that you are breaking the output stream by writing `\0` to it.

However, reading on, I spotted [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

```
std::string stdstrAnswer = stdqueAnswers.front();
async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(stdstrAnswer),
            [this, self](error_code ec, size_t /*length*/) {
                if (!ec) {
                    do_read();
                }
            });
stdqueAnswers.pop();
```

You're passing a reference to `stdstrAnswer`, a local variable, which goes out of scope before `async_write` completes. That's a problem regardless of whether you included `stdqueAnswers.pop()`. Instead consider:

```
auto self(shared_from_this());
async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(stdqueAnswers.front()),
            [this, self](error_code ec, size_t /*length*/) {
                if (!ec) {
                    stdqueAnswers.pop();
                    do_read();
                }
            });
```

Of course, there's

- the code smell of unused `length` parameter to `do_write` (what was it intended for?)
- the fact that `stdqueAnswers` is used, but never pushed to
- the fact that `stdqueAnswers` queues answers, but the queue is never drained: instead, after a single `async_write` there is **always** just `do_read`, so the queue won't function as a queue.

It feels like you're trying to have full-duplex IO. In that case you need to change from the half-duplex model that you currently still use:

[image]

To something conceptually like

[image]

There's some catches how to start the write loop when the first message is pushed to the out queue. See `enqueueAnswer` in the code below, which shows what I expect you were after:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/970a8e5f13ffa374)**

```
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/write.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
    session(tcp::socket socket)
        : socket_(std::move(socket))
    {
    }

    void start()
    {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        // dispatch not strictly necessary for single-threaded contexts
        dispatch(
            socket_.get_executor(),
            [this, self]
            {
                do_read();
            });
    }

private:
    // all private member functions assumed to be on-strand
    std::queue<std::string> stdqueAnswers;

    void handleCommand(std::string&& cmd)
    {
        std::cout << std::quoted(cmd);

        if(cmd.find_first_not_of(' ') != std::string::npos)
        {
            // There's a non-space.
            enqueueAnswer("Handled command: '" + cmd + "'\n");
        }
    }

    void enqueueAnswer(std::string&& answer)
    {
        stdqueAnswers.push(std::move(answer));

        if(stdqueAnswers.size() == 1)
        {
            do_write();
        }
    }

    void do_read()
    {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        socket_.async_read_some( //
            boost::asio::buffer(data_),
            [this, self](error_code ec, size_t length)
            {
                if(! ec)
                {
                    handleCommand({data_, length});
                    do_read();
                }
            });
    }

    void do_write()
    {
        if(stdqueAnswers.empty())
            return;
        auto self(shared_from_this());

        async_write(
            socket_,
            boost::asio::buffer(stdqueAnswers.front()),
            [this, self](error_code ec, size_t)
            {
                if(! ec)
                {
                    stdqueAnswers.pop();
                    do_write();
                }
            });
    }

    tcp::socket socket_;
    char data_[8096];
};

class server
{
public:
    server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, std::uint16_t port)
        : acceptor_{io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)}
    {
        acceptor_.listen();
        do_accept();
    }

private:
    void do_accept()
    {
        acceptor_.async_accept(
            make_strand(acceptor_.get_executor()),
            [this](error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
            {
                if(! ec)
                {
                    std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
                    do_accept();
                }
            });
    }

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    server s(ioc, 8989);

    ioc.run();
}
```

With a demo client:

```
sleep 1; printf 'hello\nworld\nnull chars \0 are the best\nbye' | netcat 127.0.0.1 8989 | xxd
```

Seems to handle `\0` characters just fine:

[image]